# Checkbox неправильно меняется в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const input = React.createRef()
  const input2 = React.createRef()

  function handleClick() {
    setState(input2.current.value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input type="checkbox" ref={input} checked={state}/>
      <select ref={input2} onChange={handleClick}>
        <option value={false}>OFF</option>
        <option value={true}>ON</option>
      </select>
    </>
  );
}
```

Нужно при соответствуещем выбраном поле в select делать checkbox вкл или выкл. Но вылазит такая ошибка (уведомление)

*Warning: Received the string `true` for the boolean attribute `checked`. Although this works, it will not work as expected if you pass the string "false". Did you mean checked={true}?*

Comment: То, на что ругается реакт, можно пофиксить так:       checked={state === "true"? true : false}

Comment: Ошибка не ушла, но проблема решилась. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пару замечаний:

- Чисто в этом компоненте вам не нужны `ref`-ы вообще (если конечно - это полный код компоненты)
- В каком бы виде вы не писали в `value`, тега `option` данные, они всегда будут в строчном виде (сделал вывод в консоль чтобы убедились в этом). По этой причине вам на вход приходили не `true` и `false`, а `"true"` и `"false"`. И как мы знаем в JS **НЕ** пустая строка при конвертации в булевую переменную всегда даст `true`, следовательно `checkbox` всегда будет помеченным, кроме как начального состояния т.к. там действительно сначала стоит булевая переменная `false`
- Проверять условие в самом аттрибуте не стоит. Не то чтобы это не будет работать, а так код будет чище и понятнее, если `handleClick` сам займётся всеми нужными преобразованиями и уже вставит нужное значение
- Писать проверку типа `x === y ? true : false` бессмысленно, т.к. `x === y` и так вернёт вам `true`, если они равны и `false`. если они не равны

Код:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  function handleClick(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    
    console.log(value, typeof value);
    setState(value === 'true');
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={state}/>
      <select onChange={handleClick}>
        <option value={false}>OFF</option>
        <option value={true}>ON</option>
      </select>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```